# SQL Order in two columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I am going nuts trying to fix these small issues. I'm trying to have the `DATE_TIME` be in order and want the `MISTI` to be in order. The screenshot shows the `MISTI` in order but not the dates. Is there any way I can remove the 2019 date out of the query too? THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!

```
    select To_Char(state_out_dttm, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS date_time, PARM, TRK_ID as MISTI,
num_value AS PM_NUMBER
from trk_id_parm
Where trk_id IN ('IMV01','IMV02','IMV03', 'IMV04', 'IMV05')
and state = 'SMM'
and PARM = '4440'
order by MISTI ASC, DATE_TIME DESC;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Q: Did you store your DATE_TIME column in the database as a date/time type ... or as a TEXT type?  Q: What database are you using?

Comment: I stored it as a date/time type

Comment: So are you saying that `state_out_dttm` is actually datetime, not text?

Comment: It should be date/time type. I will add a screenshot of a generic query.

Answer (score 1):

As it appears that your `state_out_dttm` column is actually *text*, and not a date, you should be using `TO_DATE`, not `TO_CHAR`, to first convert to a bona fide date before trying to sort:

```sql
SELECT
    TO_DATE(state_out_dttm, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS date_time,
    PARM,
    TRK_ID AS MISTI,
    num_value AS PM_NUMBER
FROM trk_id_parm
WHERE
    trk_id IN ('IMV01','IMV02','IMV03', 'IMV04', 'IMV05') AND
    state = 'SMM' AND
    PARM = '4440' AND
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(state_out_dttm, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) <> 2019
ORDER BY
    MISTI,
    TO_DATE(state_out_dttm, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') DESC;
```

Comment: I'm getting a ORA-01843: not a valid month

Comment: Then maybe the `state_out_dttm` column has bad/invalid data in it.  Another reason to never store dates as text `:-)`

Comment: is there any way I can verify it's stored as a text?

Comment: Sure: [describe tablename](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12019.htm)  PS: I sure hope this isn't a production database and you don't have "admin" privileges :(